# Python in Maya - Select x faces every x faces

Tags: python, select, maya

I'm a newbie in Python and programming in general, and for my courses I have modelized a tree, and I would like to make a script that would allow me to delete one row of faces of the tree trunk each two rows. I would like the result to look like a ribbon trunk you see? Delete one row of faces, keep the next one, delete the next... and so on.

While looking on the internet and on this site, I have come to do this:

```
    TrunkFaces=cmds.ls("Trunk.f[0:414]", fl=True) 
    DeletedTrunkFaces=TrunkFaces[::5]
    print DeletedTrunkFaces
    cmds.delete(DeletedTrunkFaces)
```

So basically it's cool because it deletes a face every 5 face, but it's not enough for what I would like, I would like the program to delete 12 faces every two rows (as my trunk is a cube with 2 edge loops per face which makes 3 subfaces per face).

I'm deeply sorry if this has already been answered somewhere, I couldn't find the answer. Thanks for your help!

Popi

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're going to run into is that there's no guarantee that the face rows are consistent throughout; it might be true now but if you delete a face or a vertex later the ordering won't be consistent any more (indeed, it's going to change the ordering every time you run it.

However, to grab N faces out of every R rows you can do something like this:

```
def get_face_subsets(object, row_size, take):
    faces_count = cmds.polyEvaluate(object, f=True)
    subsets = [] 
    # first break the original indexes into a list-of-lists
    # each containing <row_size> items
    for range_set in range(faces_count / row_size):
        start = range_set * row_size
        subsets.append(range(faces_count)[start: start+row_size + 1])

    results = []
    # now loop over the lists, grabbing the first <take> items
    # from each
    for subset in subsets:
         for f in subset[:take]:
             results.append(object + ".f[%i]" % f)
    return results

get_face_subsets('pSphere1', 5, 2)

// Result: ['pSphere1.f[0]', 'pSphere1.f[1]', 'pSphere1.f[5]', 'pSphere1.f[6]'...
```

There are better ways to do this from a programming standpoint but this way is easy to follow.  The main trick is to use `polyEvaluate` and `range` to get the indices as a predictable stream of numbers, then split that into smaller groups ('rows') and use slices to take a subset of those

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. God it seems scary for a beginner like me but I am going to try that. I'll keep you posted. Thank you! Could it be also achieved using what I heard was called "regular expressions"?

Thanks :)

Comment: A regular expression is a special string designed to match patterns.  That would work here but I suspect it will be much harder to write since regex's are a weird mini-language of their own